# How to decrypt the luks encrypted hard disk password automatically using tpm2 | ubutnu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, disk-encryption, luks, tpm

I have encrypted my hard disks using default method(Luks encryption) present in ubuntu 18.04 and I have tpm2, now i wanted to save my passwords on tpm2 device and decrypt automatically without entering the password manually at every boot. How do I do this?

I'm using tpm2-tss 2.0.0, tpm2-abrmd 2.0.1 , tpm2-tools 3.1.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the password was automatically entered, what would be the use of encryption at all? Security and convenience are at opposing ends of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

[clevis](https://github.com/latchset/clevis) with its tpm2 PIN and systemd, dracut or udisks2 support should do the trick.

Comment: It should do the trick but it's broken for Ubuntu 18.04 for quite some time and no one seems to care (https://github.com/latchset/clevis/issues/106)